# Correct way to use before save hooks on mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to put together a before save callback on my Mongoose model. The callback is suppose to make a GET request to an API and save the response to a field of the object. Due to the nature of node.js of it being async and the save happening before the request is done. What would be the correct way of performing such operation?

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
Schema.pre('save', function(next){
  self = this
  request.get('myapi.com/method', { param_one: this_is_myparam } , function(err, data){
    self.myField = data['myFrield']
    self.save()
    next()
  }
  next()
})
```

Am I doing the right thing? Or is there a more JavaScript/Node way of doing things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks right but remove the `self.save()` line, which will cause an unnecessary duplicate save. You just need to modify `this` during the `preSave` hook and then mongoose will do the actual save to mongodb for you.

```
Schema.pre('save', function(next){
  //Yes, good. `this` here will be your mongoose model instance
  self = this
  request.get('myapi.com/method', { param_one: this_is_myparam } , function(err, data){
    //Yes, good. All you have to do here is CHANGE the mongoose model instance
    self.myField = data['myFrield']
    //No, bad. This is extraneous. By definition, mongoose is going to save your model
    //automatically after the "preSave" hook completes, so you should remove this.
    //self.save()
    next()
  }
  //No, bad. Remove this as well. You need to wait for the response to come back
  //next()
})
```

Comment: I can't do that. this within the callback function of the request is the request itself and not my model, and it's the reason why I asked because I feel that the second save shouldn't be there.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I said. I put your snippet into my answer with some comments. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Peter, thank you for your patience & answer. Perhaps I'm not making myself clear on why your solution does not work. Since the request is made Async (node won't wait until the request comes back before saving) therefor node has already saved the object when the assignation is made resulting in a blank each and every single time. Does this makes sense now?

Comment: Ah, we're looking at different lines. Yes, you also have an extraneous `next()` call that is an error. The preSave function is also asynchronous, which is why it uses a `next` callback. Just invoke `next()` inside your `request.get` handler and all will be well. Remove the other call to `next()`.

Comment: Ah! Now I get it and it works, I had to remove the second next.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience. Could you update your answer so that I can accept it?